# How to do the conversion so that double and Boolean value comes without double quote

Tags: c#

I have JSON file coming from 3rd party systems where all "string", "double" and "Boolean" comes as double quote as string data.

```
 [{"Key":"Key1","Value":"Value1"},{"Key":"Key2","Value":"80"},{"Key":"Key3","Value":"true"}]
```

I need to convert accordingly to double, boolean and string, I have defined a class like, value as "object"

```
 public class Data
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize the data like,

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TEMP\data.json"));
```

but the value is coming in double quote as this treats as string ,

[image]
[image]

How to do the conversion so that double and boolean value comes without double quote,

[image]

Comment: You can use online tool (e.g. [this one](https://json2csharp.com/)) to convert json to classes. In given json all values are strings (forget about double, bools, etc). Deserialize them as string and those what you think are doubles [convert to double](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11399439/1997232) (the good question is how do you know what are double, perhaps by using `TryParse` method and if it works).

Comment: can't you just cast them into bool?

Comment: @Gilad, you can't cast string to bool, you need to either parse or [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20893956/1997232).

Comment: Use _"Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste JSON As Classes"_, which will generate appropriate c# code for deserializing your JSON string.

Comment: You might want to consider deserialising the data to a Dictionary object rather than your own 'Data' class.  Something like this:

`var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TEMP\data.json"));`

Comment: @PeterG. could you show some code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@user584018 you can write your JsonConverters, there are many ways you could, I taken the code from post and modified based on your criteria. [JsonConverters and object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174991/jsonconverters-and-object-properties)

```
public class PolymorphicConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(object);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (double.TryParse(token.ToString(), out double doubleValue))
            return doubleValue;
        if (bool.TryParse(token.ToString(), out bool boolValue))
            return boolValue;
        return token.ToString();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 

}

public class Data
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(PolymorphicConverter))]
    public object Value { get; set; }
}
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\TEMP\data.json"));
```